# jquery lib in googleapis is causing error: Invalid value for property: zoom

Tags: jquery, ajax, zooming

Why is line 5 in the following code block giving me a "Invalid value for property: zoom" error? I am running it in Opera 11.62 and catching the error in Dragonfly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // google chart built here from JSON pulled through php call
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The minimized version of jQuery (at least version <= 1.7.1) needs a tweak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer 5.5 and above support the non-standard `zoom` CSS property. It sets the magnification scale of an element.

There’s no CSS3 equivalent to this property yet.

So you have an error in Opera because it doesn't know about such property. This property is for IE only.

In your case this Opera console error is produced by jQuery library - jQuery knows about  `zoom` property and tries to use it.

[Here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom) you can find more detailed description of this problem and also browsers compatibility table for `zoom` property.

Comment: Awesome, thanks webbandit! I'll see if I can replicate the error again and figure out a work around, perhaps a later version of JQuery.